# Edit image with linear gradient and convert to base64 React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I have been using library "canvas" to edit an image (by URL) with linear-gradient and I've been using some methods. But I can't get properly the results yet.

I used these methods with canvas, but anything works well with React. Do you know another method to edit an image with a linear gradient and convert it to base64?

---

**First method**

```
    import { loadImage, createCanvas } from 'canvas'

    useEffect(() => {
      const coversheet = 'https://...'
      const canvas = createCanvas('600', '286')
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

      loadImage(coversheet).then( image => {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 340, 515, 70, 70)
        let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 170, 0)
        gradient.addColorStop(0, 'white')
        gradient.addColorStop(1, 'red')
        ctx.fillStyle = gradient
        ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100)
      })

      let base64 = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg')
      setCoversheetSrc(base64)
    }, [])
```

With this method I'm not getting anything, this returns a black image (it's black when is 'image/jpeg' type) in the base64.

---

**Second method**

```
  import { createCanvas, Image } from 'canvas'

  useEffect(() => { 
    const coversheet = 'https://...'
    const canvas = createCanvas('600', '286')
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

    const img = new Image()
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'
    img.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage(this, 340, 515, 70, 70)
      let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 170, 0)
      gradient.addColorStop(0, 'white')
      gradient.addColorStop(1, 'red')
      ctx.fillStyle = gradient
      ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100)
    }
    img.src = coversheet

    let base64 = canvas.toDataURL()
    setCoversheetSrc(base64)
  }, [])
```

With this code I get this error message:

> TypeError: canvas__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Image is not a
> constructor.

Pointing out this line "const img = new Image()"

---

**Third method:**

```
  import { loadImage, createCanvas } from 'canvas'

  useEffect(() => {
      const runCanvas = async () => {
      const coversheet = 'https://...'

      const canvas = await createCanvas('600', '286')
      const ctx = await canvas.getContext('2d')
      const image = await loadImage(coversheet)

      ctx.drawImage(image, 340, 515, 70, 70)
      let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 170, 0)
      gradient.addColorStop(0, 'white')
      gradient.addColorStop(1, 'red')
      ctx.fillStyle = gradient
      ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100)

      let base64 = await canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg')
      setCoversheetSrc(base64)
    }
    runCanvas()
  }, [])
```

With this I'm getting this error:

> Unhandled Rejection (SecurityError): Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on
> 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

Answer (score 0):

1. `import { createCanvas, Image } from 'canvas'` is for version 1.x of the library as documented [here](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/tree/v1.x). You are most likely using 2.x.
2. "Tainted canvases may not be exported." means you've loaded a cross-domain image into the canvas. You therefore cannot call `toDataURL` on it, [as documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image#Security_and_tainted_canvases), for security reasons.

You will have to either add appropriate CORS headers on that image response, or, if the server is not under your control, you can alternatively proxy it through your own and serve it with the appropriate CORS headers. These are properly documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image#Security_and_tainted_canvases).

Comment: **About 1.** I changed the version to 1.x, but now it's giving this error from importing the library. _TypeError: Cannot set property 'parseFont' of undefined_

**About 2.** I have control in the server, the question... Is there another manner to configure crossOrigin like in the **Second method**, but without constructor Image()?

Comment: @LuisCarlos Yes you can, see this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-crossorigin

Comment: It works! I just wrote `image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous` after the line `const image = await loadImage(coversheet)` in the **Third Method**.
But I don't know what is happening now because the image is returned like this:
[example](https://jsfiddle.net/Zolyder/psm2t4uL/5/).

I want the effect in the image, no on top of the image.
Do you know how to do this Sergiu?